# How do I run a Python program to periodically update an existing pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, timer, python-multithreading

I am creating panel data by importing from a database's API using a function called `instance` which generates a pd.DataFrame column of 200 dict objects, each containing the values for the same variables (e.g. "Number of comments" and "Number of views") corresponding to one of the 200 members of the panel.

This data is constantly being updated in real time and the database does not store its data. In other words, if one wants to keep track of how the data progresses over time, one must manually call the function `instance` every desired period (e.g. every hour).

I am wondering how I would go about writing a program to passively run my `instance` function every hour appending it to every other hour's execution. For this purpose, I have found the `threading` module of potential interest, particularly its `Timer` program, but have had difficulty applying it effectively. This is what I have come up with:

```
def instance_log(year, month, day, loglength):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()    
    log = instance(year,month,day)
    t = threading.Timer(60, log.join(instance(year, month, day)))
    t.start()
    if datetime.datetime.now() > start+datetime.timedelta(hours=loglength):
        t.cancel()
        return(log)
```

I tried running this program for loglength=1 (i.e. update the `log` DataFrame every minute for an hour), but it failed. Any help diagnosing what I did wrong or suggesting an alternate means of achieving what I'd want would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, to avoid confusion, I should clarify the inputs `year`, `month`, and `day` are used to identify the 200 panel members so that I use the same panelists for each iteration of instance.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing too much about your `Instance` (*assuming it's a class*) API this is how I would do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from __future__ import print_function


from circuits import Event, Component, Timer


class Instance(object):
    """My Instance Object"""


class App(Component):

    def init(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

        # Create a scheduled event every hour
        Timer(60 * 60, Event.create("log_instance"), persist=True).register(self)

    def log_instance(self, year, month, day, loglength):
        """Event Handler for scheduled log_instance Event"""
        log = self.instance(year, month, day)
        print(log)  # Do something with log


instance = Instance()  # create instance?
App(instance).run()
```

This doesn't use Python's [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) library but provides a reusable and composable event-driven structure that you can extend using the [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) framework. (*caveat: I'm the author of this framework/library and am biased towards Event-Driven approaches!*).

**NB:** This is untested code as I'm not familiar with your exact requirements or your `Instance`'s API (*nor have you really shown that in the question*).